# How to turn off system sound when starting video recording in Windows 10 mobile (UWP app)

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I would like to mute the system sound when starting/stopping video recording in Windows 10 mobile. There are apps like 6sec and Instagram UWP Beta that can do it. I did research about MediaCapture API but found nothing related to the problem.

Comment: you means background music??

Comment: the *click* sound when you start / stop recording. Same sound you hear when using native camera app.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the system did it automatically..
A possible workaround can be to play a media file before starting the camera, like a super short mp3 file with no sound..
I haven't tested it, but it should work.. Maybe there's a better solution.. Let me know!